# printing arrngements

Tags: java

How can I do arrangements. of numbers... such that each new number formed out of arrangement has at max a difference of 1 from prev maxima.

e.g.
if input is k=1 output will be 1

if k =2 outputs are : 11, 12
2,1 is wrong as left most has to be 1 always.

if k = 3 outputs are: 111,112, 121, 122, 123

if k = 4 : 1111,1112,1121,1122,1123,1212,1211,1213,1223,1221, 1222, 1233, 1234

1423 is wrong diff b/w 1 and 4 is 3.
1243 is wrong diff b/w 2 and 4 is 2....

How I do this using DP, if possible?

This is one of the solution for above question... can anyone help me to understand this code...
Thanks in advance...

```
public class MaxOneDiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 4;
        getList(k);
    }

    public static void getList(int k) {
        int arr[] = new int[k];
        int index = 0;
        printRecList(k, arr, index, k);
    }

    public static void printRecList(int k, int arr[], int index, int range) {
        if (k == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i <= range; i++) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    arr[index] = i;
                    printRecList(k - 1, arr, index + 1, range);
                } else {
                    int t = arr[index-1]-i;
                    t = t > 0 ? t : -t;
                    if (t < 2) {
                        arr[index] = i;
                        printRecList(k - 1, arr, index + 1, range);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the easy part:

```
public static void getList(int k) {
    int arr[] = new int[k];
    int index = 0;
    printRecList(k, arr, index, k);
}
```

This is a helper to the Print Recursive List function, just setting up the initial stuff.

```
public static void printRecList(int k, int arr[], int index, int range) {
```

This is a recursive function, it should (and does) contain two main parts:

1. A base case (here, when k==0 )
2. A non-base case which does something, reducing the problem into smaller problem(s), and recurses.

### Base case:

```
    if (k == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
```

If k==0, print out the numbers in the array from left to right, then put a new-line at the end.

### Non-Base Case: (the more complicated part)

```
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= range; i++) {
            if (index == 0) {
                arr[index] = i;
                printRecList(k - 1, arr, index + 1, range);
            } else {
                int t = arr[index-1]-i;
                t = t > 0 ? t : -t;
                if (t < 2) {
                    arr[index] = i;
                    printRecList(k - 1, arr, index + 1, range);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

'i' goes from 1 to range,

The helper function calls this with index=0, so the first/top level of recursion, is composed of setting the first element (element 0) of the array to i, and calling the recursive method.

Never again will index == 0 in the recursive calls, so we turn our attention to the else clause.

Here we want to know if we can assign the value i to the next element over, so we check to see if the absolute value of  elementToLeft minus i  is greater than or equal to 2.

If 'i' is valid to assign in that position (i.e. it is only 1 or 0 different from the value to the left, and 'i' can only get as high as range from the for loop.)

Then we assign it, and check the next position over.

This ends when we have reached the last element in the array.